# Using firebase functions emulator with cloud SQL proxy

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, firebase-tools

I deployed a firebase https function that calls a GCP MySQL instance and returns some data. How can I run this function in the firebase function emulator?

I loaded the function into the emulator along with a simple helloWorld https function. That returns nicely with the local URL (http://localhost:5001/INSTANCE/us-central1/helloWorld). The locally run SQL https function, however, returns
`{"errno":-4058,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"connect","address":"/cloudsql/(deleted)","fatal":true}`
... where I've deleted the instance connection name.

Next, I run gcloud_sql_proxy on my PC, and it claims to be listening on 127.0.0.1:3306. The https function continues to return the exact same error above, so I'm not sure if the emulated function is going through my gcloud_sql_proxy or still trying to connect to the cloud SQL directly - I am guessing the latter.

Should I also re-instrument the function itself to connect using host+port (127.0.0.1, 3306) versus the unix socketpath method that it's currently using? I was hoping the emulator would automagically do that so I can avoid going down that rabbit hole, as the cloud documentation only provided the socketpath method. But I do plan to try that next.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, I think the emulator is looking for a Unix socket and it sounds like you're starting the Cloud SQL Proxy with a TCP socket.

Try using a Unix socket whose path matches your function. Something like:

```
cloud_sql_proxy -dir /cloudsql
```

This will create a Unix socket for all SQL instances in your active gcloud project.

Comment: I get "unsupported network: unix"  when trying that or other variations of that. Based on your suggestion, I have tried ` ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE -dir /cloudsql, 
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE=unix -dir /cloudsql and ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE=unix:/cloudsql`. Thanks for the suggestion. I got the proxy working with HOST & IP but would like to get it working with UNIX so I don't have to change the stored procedure instrumentation.

Comment: If you're running on Windows, you won't be able to use a Unix socket at the moment. We do have an issue to fix that: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/84. In the meantime, probably the simplest thing to do is to run with a TCP socket in dev. Feel free to comment on that issue as well to help boost its priority.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it will be helpful if I switch to Linux. My main need is to do function development locally, because function deployment to firebase is so slow. So as long as the proxy works with host/ip I am good. Down the road, if unix sockets will be available in Windows that would be even better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch over to WSL on Windows to work locally on GCP Cloud Functions that need to connect to a Cloud SQL database.  In my case, I needed to test writing to MySQL.  Note that you need to create a firewall rule to connect from your computer, or at the least go through the steps to connect with a client tool like MySQL Workbench.

You first need to set up Cloud SQL Proxy, namely these steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-auth-proxy#linux-64-bit):

`curl -o cloud-sql-proxy https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.0.0/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64`

`chmod +x cloud-sql-proxy`

You will change `socketPath` to `cloud_sql_proxy` and use 127.0.0.1 for the `host`. This is an example using [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql):

```
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
      //socketPath: '/cloudsql/my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql',
      cloud_sql_proxy: '-dir /cloudsql',
      //host: '34.99.123.99',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: '3306',
      user: 'youruser',
      password: process.env.DB_PW,
      database: 'my-gcp-sql'
    });
```

You then start the proxy and your Cloud Function in one command, using an identity that has Cloud SQL connect permissions, for example:

```
foo@foo-foo:/mnt/c/Users/foo/source/repos/my-dw-gcp/cloud-functions/a_cloud_function$ ./cloud-sql-proxy --credentials-file /mnt/c/foo/bar/my-dw-file.json my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql & npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=getData
[2] 1329
2023/03/07 17:45:52 Authorizing with the credentials file at "/mnt/c/foo/bar/my-dw-file.json"
2023/03/07 17:45:52 [my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql] Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306
2023/03/07 17:45:52 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!
Serving function...
Function: getData
Signature type: http
URL: http://localhost:8080/
2023/03/07 17:48:28 [my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:50560
2023/03/07 17:48:29 [my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql] instance closed the connection
```

**UPDATE**

You can do the same thing from a Windows command prompt.  You just need two terminals.  Download the proxy client from the link above:

- cloud-sql-proxy.x64.exe --credentials-file C:\foo\my-dw-file.json my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql
- npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=getData

The only problem is that you **will** need socketPath and the public IP (or private IP if you set that up) for the Cloud Function running on GCP.  In that case, you want a dev and prod config, something like this:

```
    const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

    if (environment == 'development') {
      const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        cloud_sql_proxy: '-dir /cloudsql',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        ...etc 
    } else {
      const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        socketPath: '/cloudsql/my-dw:us-east4:my-mysql',
        host: '34.99.123.99',
        etc...
```